# Access IMappingOperationOptions dictionary in .ForMember() without IValueResolver

Tags: .net, automapper

I'm trying to map two objects and the destination has data that require additional data sources. These are the classes:

```
public class SourceClass {
  public int SrcValueOne { get; set; }
}

public class DestClass { 
  public int DestValueOne { get; set; }

  public int ValueFromConfig { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigSettings { 
  public int ConfigValueOne { get; set; }
}
```

I need to map values in the SourceClass to DestClass and, at the same time, pass a populated ConfigSettings object (at runtime) to the Map() and read some values from there. Thus far all I've found is a `ResolveUsing` method which doesn't seem ideal. I'm wondering if there's a way to do something similar to this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestClass>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.DestValueOne, src => src.MapFrom(a => a.SrcValueOne))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.ValueFromConfig, src => opt.ResolveUsing<ConfigSettings>.FromMember(config => config.ConfigValueOne);
```

I figured out how to pass the populated object at runtime in the `Map()` using the Items collection, but can't figure out if there's a way to access it in the ResolveUsing **without** creating Resolvers and/or using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ConfigSettings, DestCLass>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.ValueFromConfig, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ConfigValueOne))
   .ForMember(dest => dest.DestValueOne, opt => opt.Ignore());
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestClass>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.DestValueOne, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => a.SrcValueOne))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.ValueFromConfig, opt => opt.Ignore());

var dest = Mapper.Map(config);
Mapper.Map(source, dest);
```

This is the simplest option you have if you don't want to introduce another class.

Adding a new class can help to encapsulate this to only one Map call:

```
public class ComplexSource
{
    public ConfigSettings Config{get;set;}
    public SourceClass SourceData{get;set;}
}

Mapper.CreateMap<ComplexSource, DestClass>()....
```

Comment: Thanks! That's certainly an option, although I'm still wondering if there's a way to read something that was passed into the Map() dynamically, without creating multiple maps, etc?

Comment: That's why there are resolvers :). Anyway, see my edit for another option.